# C# WCF - How do I convert an incoming xml string into a model with get and set?

Tags: c#, wcf

C#.NET in WCF Service

**Receiving XML String in Service Parameter** 
This is a POST Request. I am receiving an xml string of a simple format like in my wcf service.

```
<query>
    <testval>Hello123</testval>
    <testval2>Bye123</testval2>
</query>
```

I have a static method that extract the nodes of the xml string. 
E.g., `string testval = XMLString.ExtractNode(xmlString, "testval") which returns Hello123. Is it possible to receive this xml string in a model with` {get; set;}`?

**My POST Service function**

```cs
public string Test(string xmlString)
{
    // code 
}
```

I would like to receive the "xmlString" above using a model (in a class) but I would need to extract the nodes.

```cs
public class TestModel
{
    public string testval {get; set;}
    public string testval2 {get; set;}
}
```

Then my POST service function would just  be

```cs
public string Test(TestModel testmodel)
{
    // code 
    Console.WriteLine(testmodel.testval) // "Hello123"
    Console.WriteLine(testmodel.testval2) // "Bye123"
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to get the value of the xml using the get set method,

Comment: yes @Jiayao currently receiving the xml as a string

Answer (score 1):

I saw an example that you can refer to:

Model:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="payload")]
    public class Payload {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="firstname")]
        public string Firstname { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="secondname")]
        public string Secondname { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName="number")]
        public string Number { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName="payloads")]
    public class Payloads {
        [XmlElement(ElementName="payload")]
        public List<Payload> Payload { get; set; }
    }
```

IService:

```
 [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
             ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
             BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
             UriTemplate = "GetPay")]
    Payload GetPay();
```

Service:

```
 public Payload GetPay()
            {
                return new Payload();
            }
```